# Adding an interactive tile to a Bokeh plot using CustomJS

Tags: python-3.x, plot, callback, bokeh, interactive

I have an interactive Bokeh plot that uses CheckBoxGroup to plot different combinations. I wanted to be able to modify the title each time I changed the combinations rather than having to go through changing the title in the code and generating the plot again.

I am a lot familiar with CustomJS, but I tried the following (...only title excerpt):

```
p = figure(title = 'Default title that appears',
      toolbar_location = 'right')
.
.
update_title = CustomJS(args =dict(source=source, text = text),
                    code ="""
                const data = source.data;
                var text = text.value;

                text = text.value;

                source.change.emit();
""")
text_group = TextInput(title = 'Title', value = "Default value", callback = update_title)
show(column(p,checkbox_group, text_group))
```

The result that I get shows a title box but nothing happens when I change the title.

[I essentially want to do this:](https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders)

But with CustomJS instead of Python callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the title to the callback. I discovered that plot title is a Bokeh model, so all the regular manipulations apply. Your callback could look something like this:

```
update_title = CustomJS(args=dict(title=plot.title), code="""
    title.text = cb_obj.value
""")
```

and the full example would be

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
plot = figure(y_range=(-10, 10), plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title='my sine wave')
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
update_title = CustomJS(args=dict(title=plot.title), code="""
    title.text = cb_obj.value
""")
text = TextInput(title='Enter title', value='my sine wave', callback=update_title)
layout = row(
    plot,
    text
)
output_file('title_change.html', title='change title')
show(layout)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!